# extend expiry period in provisioning profile

Tags: iphone

i have a provisioning profile whose expiry time period is 3 months, 
how can i change this period from 3 month to 1 year?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the default settings is 3 months and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but, i have seen a provisioning profile with expiry time period of 1 year.

Comment: The old profiles where valid for one year, then Apple changed them to 3 months.